# Function Derivative and Differentiability

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Assume that $f:\textbf{R}^n\rightarrow\textbf{R}$ is differentiable on $\textbf{R}^n$.  Prove that the function $F:\textbf{R}\rightarrow\textbf{R}$ given by $F(t) := f(t, t^2, . . . , t^n)$ is differentiable on $\textbf{R}$ and find its derivative.

I do not understand how we can show $F(t)$ is differentiable based on $f$. Differentiability theorem states that $f$ has directional vectors in all directions but does this imply $F(t)$ is differentiable?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you already heard of chain rule?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Let $\gamma:\textbf{R}\rightarrow\textbf{R}^{n}$ be expressed as $\gamma(t) = (t,t^{2},\ldots,t^{n})$. Then $F = f\circ\gamma$, from whence we have
\begin{align*}
F^{\prime}(t) = \langle\nabla f(\gamma(t)),\gamma^{\prime}(t)\rangle
\end{align*}

where $\nabla f(\gamma(t))$ is the gradient of $f$ applied to the point $\gamma(t)$.

Answer (score 0):

It is a composition of two differentiable function: 
$t\mapsto(t,t^2,...,t^n)\mapsto f(t,...,t^n)$.

So using chain rule the derivative is $$\sum_{i=1}^nt^{i-1}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(t,...,t^n).$$

Comment: what is xi? please

Comment: and howd you come up with that, im a little confused (I tried to derive it myself and have like it^i-1 with the extra i)